# Trans-Neptunian Dwarf Planet near Heliopause

Tags: dwarf-planets, trans-neptunian-object

Is there any reason to think a Trans-Neptunian dwarf planet, the size of Pluto, could not exist in a Keplerian orbit 120AU from the Sun?

If such an object existed, and came within 0.1AU of the heliopause, is there anything about the environment near the heliopause that would prevent a stable orbit.

Comment: When you say “exist”, do you mean *in orbit* or just passing by? Is there a reason you’re so precise about proximity to the heliopause? What definition of Dwarf Planet are you using? It might be worthwhile if you [edit] your question to add some detail. :-)

Comment: @Chappo If I said I'm asking the question for a novel I am writing, would that make it invalid for this Stack Exchange?

Comment: The *reason* for your question doesn't make it invalid here, but the lack of clarity might. To make it a fitting question for our site, why not be more direct and ask whether the nature of the heliopause makes a stable orbit impossible, and if not impossible, is it plausible that a large body like Pluto could form that far out.

Comment: Also, are you aware of our other SE site, [Worldbuilding.se]? The blurb says it's "a question and answer site for writers/artists using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings." Sounds very much like a site you might enjoy exploring. :-)

Comment: @Chappo. I didn't consider Worldbuilding because I wasn't interested in discussing imaginary worlds and settings, rather the real possibility of whether it could exist.  I had assumed this site would give me a more thorough answer.  If I misunderstood Worldbuilding I will delete this and repost it at Worldbuilding, if that is more appropriate.

Comment: There is a [reality-check] tag in worldbuilding that you use to stipulate that you want answers on whether or not something could exist/function in real life. There are some very knowledgeable people on worldbuilding, and the userbase sees much overlap with physics/astronomy/maths etc. So yeah, worldbuilding is very much the place.

Comment: @mistertribs that sounds a little bit like punitive closing. The OP is probably asking in good faith. I think the question and the answer can both be refined a little bit without any need to close it down.

Comment: @mistertribs Reading the question; **it looks perfectly clear to me**. Talk about what is or isn't "in another users head" is unproductive and incompatible with Stack Exchange. I think your answer is quite helpful and I'm the one who up voted it. I think the thing about being within 0.1 or 0.01 AU is overblown. Not everyone who asks a question about the heliopause comes in with knowledge of its exact shape. I don't think it's "grounds for closure" but instead it's an opportunity for learning.

Comment: As of 2020, 2018 VG18's distance from the Sun is 123.5 AU and is thought to be close to heliopause.

Comment: @NilayGhosh You should make that an answer.

Comment: I have added an answer as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heliopause is believed to be at a distance of about 123 AU away from the Sun.](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition/heliopause) Now, if you look at the [list of farthest body in the solar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_most_distant_from_the_Sun), you will see two bodies located approximately at that distance: **[2018 VG18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_VG18)** and predicted **[FarFarOut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FarFarOut)** (124.12 AU and ~140 AU from the sun as of June 2020 respectively). They are considered the farthest TNOs in the solar system.

For comparison, Voyager 1 and Voyager 2 are the two space probes which left the solar system is now 149.36 AU and 124 AU from the sun as of June 2020. Also you can see some of the [near-parabolic comets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_near-parabolic_comets) originating from that distance.